# How to extract images stored in database in view in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

I am trying to show an image of each trainer when viewed. The images of trainers are taken from a form and are stored in the database. Now I want to extract images. Please help Me.
Adding the code for more clarity.I am not sure whether I am following the right code for the same.

This is my the code I have added in view:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'name',
        'email:email',
        'phone',
        'age',
        'gender',
        'experience',
        'training_category',
        'expectation',
        'professional_certificate',
        'special_clients',
        'time_zones',
        'certificates',
        'document',
        'id',
        'timestamp',

        'status',
        [

            'attribute'=>'photo',
            'value'=>yii::getAlias('@trainerImgUrl') . '/' .$model->photo,
            // 'value'=>Yii::getAlias('@web').'/'.$model->photo,
            'format'=>['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']]
        ]

    ],
]) ?>
```

This is the model code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'email', 'phone', 'age', 'gender', 'experience', 'training_category', 'expectation', 'professional_certificate', 'special_clients', 'time_zones', 'certificates', 'photo', 'document', 'status'], 'required'],
        [['phone'], 'integer'],
        [['timestamp'], 'safe'],
        [['photo'],'file'],
        [['name', 'email', 'age', 'gender', 'experience', 'training_category', 'expectation', 'professional_certificate', 'special_clients', 'time_zones', 'status'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['certificates', 'photo', 'document'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'Name',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'phone' => 'Phone',
        'age' => 'Age',
        'gender' => 'Gender',
        'experience' => 'Experience',
        'training_category' => 'Training Category',
        'expectation' => 'Expectation',
        'professional_certificate' => 'Professional Certificate',
        'special_clients' => 'Special Clients',
        'time_zones' => 'Time Zones',
        'certificates' => 'Certificates',
        'photo' => 'Photo',
        'document' => 'Document',
```

Controller code:

```
 public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Creates a new JoinUs model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new JoinUs();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

         $model->save();
         $trainerId= $model->id;

        $image= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'photo');
        $imgName='tra_' .$trainerId. '.' .$image->getExtension();
         $image->saveAs(yii::getAlias('@trainerImgPath') . '/' .$imgName);
         $model->photo = $imgName ;
          $model->save();
        
       
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
```

Comment: How can we help you? You don't give us any clue about your code. I'll suggest you to read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can render it like that:

```
    [

        'attribute'=>'photo',
        'value'=> function($model){
             return Html::img(yii::getAlias('@trainerImgUrl') . '/' .$model->photo, ['alt' => 'my photo', ....// other image attributes//]); //check if your image url is correct
         }
        'format'=>'raw'
    ]
```